# Passing a kwargs parameter to a ModelForm Field constructor?

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I pass a parameter in to a ModelForm Field constructor?

```
class ThingSettingsForm(ModelForm):
    things = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label='--',queryset=self.?????)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThingSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            ?????? = instance.visible_things
            #self.fields['things'] = 
            #forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=instance.visible_things)

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = (
            'title',
            'summary',
            'things',
            )
```

In the underlying model 'things' is a models.ForeignKey, and the default of showing every possible relation is not appropriate.

Comment: It depends on how you are using this ModelForm - are you just instantiating it yourself, or are you using modelform_factory?

Comment: It is just used in a generic GET/POST view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `visible_things` is a queryset, you can change the `queryset` attribute of the form field:

```
self.fields['things'].queryset = instance.visible_things
```

It really does have to be a queryset, not an arbitrary iterable, but other than that it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a kwarg if the arg is optional:

```
myform = ThingSettingsForm(thing=<my instance>)
```

You'll have to change the init method to pop your new arg first, as super isn't expecting this arg:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('thing', None)
    super(ThingSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or if its required, just add it into the init signature:

```
def __init__(self, thing, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

and call it thus:

```
myform = ThingSettingsForm(<my instance>)
```

Comment: The kwarg was already working in my example, so this answer is not on point. I found no need to pop the kwarg prior to calling super: it seems to have no problem with the extra arg